# Replace multiple values in xarray.DataArray in a single operation

Tags: python, dictionary, replace, python-xarray

I have a raster file with integer values, and I want to replace some of these values by other values. Ideally, I am looking to specify the values to replace using a dictionary, e.g. `{10:1, 2:20}` to replace all 10 values to 1 and all 2 values by 20.

Currently my solution is to do a two-step operation using `.where` and `.fillna`, but I have to apply this process for each replacement:

```py
import xarray as xr

(
xr.DataArray([0,10,10,10,2,2,2,3])
.pipe(lambda x: x.where(x!=10).fillna(1)
.where(x!=2).fillna(20))
)
```

Of course, I can wrap the two-step operation in a function with two parameters (value to replace and value to replace with), but how do I apply it iteratively on the array? Or is there a better way to do the replacement in a single function call, e.g. the equivalent of [pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xarray does not currently have a `replace` method ([GH issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/6377)). You should be able to rewrite your code to use the `other` parameter of the [`where`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.where.html) method:

```
x = xr.DataArray([0,10,10,10,2,2,3])
x.where(x != 10, 1).where(x != 2, 20)
```